# d3.js line graph axis not displaying data correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I can't figure out why the data won't display correctly.  I think it has something to do with the scale of the axis but I can't find any solutions.  There is a line being drawn but it's to small to see.  The example I was using had a time scale of several years where as I am only doing one week.

Below is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{"close":71,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":14,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":10,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":109,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":62,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":61,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":62,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":32,"date":"9-Apr-13"},{"close":19,"date":"9-Apr-13"}];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data you've provided, there is only one instance of time: Apr 9, 2013. Since there is no difference between min and max, the x axis won't display.

If you change one date to Apr 11, It looks right. 
Bear in mind that your css says

```
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

so the actual line for the x axis won't display no matter what